# Question on soil and grass above foundation

Tags: foundation, slab, grading, soil

My wife and I just bought our dream 1960s renovation and we noticed that the yard and gravel patio area is pretty much covering up the entire foundation. Is this something we need to worry about long term? I’ve done research and it seems like the major concern is bugs and termites and wood rot. Regrading the entire yard is going to be extremely expensive to drop it 4 inches and I feel it would ruin the look too. Would it help to spray regular professional grade termite spray and maybe spray the bottom of the wood boards with extremely weather resistant top coat? Or am i worrying for no reason. I do plan on getting a professional to install gutters as well. We live in Houston, as I’m sure that matters for the topography and soil types. Foundation is cement slab.

Looking at the neighbors‘ houses they are all similar with grass and soil above the foundation.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Images:
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The elevation of those weep holes in the bottom image looks inviting for critters. I have no idea, but my first instinct is stainless steel wool if there isn't already some sort of mitigation in place.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I can definitely try to add some mesh there!